# How does Channel 5 find the people who live on isolated islands for their show?

Tags: plot-explanation, documentary, ben-fogle-new-lives-in-the-wild

*Ben Fogle: New Lives In The Wild* is a TV show on Channel 5 where an explorer called Ben Fogle visits and lives with people who have isolated themselves from the rest of society; through means such as making their own solar powered electricity and pretty much not being connected to the grid.

Now what I can't grasp is how most people in his show don't have telephones and don't use wi-fi but Ben somehow manages to find and live with these people. All these people come from different parts of the world from Mongolia to Morocco he's went and lived with people from everywhere.

How does Ben/Channel 5 manage to find these isolated people and ask them whether Ben can live with them for a few days?

Comment: It's 21 century, anyone/anything can be found. Plus they're ordinary people living in isolation, not savages. They can be persuaded to be filmed. And I won't be surprised to know that **so many** reclusive people have actually rejected the proposition (of being filmed).

Comment: But how do the channel even find half the people on there like what I mean is without wi-fi or a call service and living in isolation how can these people be found? like how does the channel even know they exist ?

Comment: I know its the 21 century but off the grid means off the grid and living in certain places like a thick rain forest or in on a frozen tundra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are an expert like Ben Fogle  might be, who likes to travel and has interest in meeting such cut-off tribes, then it is actually not that hard.

Being an isolated tribe does not mean that they have never had outside contact its just that they don't want to be integrated in the society as large.

There might have been travelers explorers who first came across such tribes. Even planes/helicopters flying over dense jungle could spot them as well. Then I am sure people write about these things. Also because of the interest generated from the general public (resulting in shows like Ben Fogle: New Lives In The Wild) or just out of personal interest the explorers would have put in an extra effort to get to know them. So that is where we get the information.

As far as finding such tribes go, try googling it and you will come up with several results. Here is one case example of how the process might look like:

1) You Google un-contacted tribes and find there is one in Andaman Islands.

2) You find out if you know any locals from this region who could tell you more about this area.

3) You pack your bags and fly to this region, consult your local guide and ensure that these tribes are safe to visit or try to find someone who can initiate contact (read: you might need some special language skills for contact).

4) Once contact is initiated you try to negotiate with them to let them film you by offering them something in exchange to what they might need (like some special food or something or even money).

Comment: fair enough didn't think of this